# VBA UserForm visible range

Tags: excel, layout, userform, vba

I have a userform with the dimensions (h*w) 180 * 240. To this userform controls are to be added by the `UserForm_Initialize()` event based on a myriad of user inputs after which the userform is to be resized . The problem I'm running into is the fact that the visible range of the userform is smaller than the actual range. To demonstrate I've inserted a second userform with the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 2
        Set ctrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        With ctrl
            Debug.Print .Name
            .Caption = i
            .BorderStyle = 1
            .Height = 10
            .Width = 10
        End With
    Next i

    Set ctrl = Me.Controls("Label1")
    With ctrl
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
    End With

    Set ctrl = Me.Controls("Label2")
    With ctrl
        .Top = Me.Height - .Height
        .Left = Me.Width - .Width
    End With
End Sub
```

which generates the following userform:
[image: USerform2 example 1]

The first label sits exactly on the top and left edge of the userform but the second label is nowhere to be seen as it isn't on the visible part of the userform.

How do I get the second label to sit exactly on the bottom and right edge of the visible part of the userform like in the image below? (I've edited the first image to show what I want)
[image]

Comment: Here's a post I rode about a method to resize a userform and its controls: http://yoursumbuddy.com/dynamically-resize-form-controls-with-anchors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `InsideHeight` and `InsideWidth` properties:

```
With ctrl
    .Top = Me.InsideHeight - .Height
    .Left = Me.InsideWidth - .Width
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick, unfortunately it's a read only property and I can't set it directly

Comment: Why would you need to?

Comment: I'm resizing the form based on user inputs, and I always want the same width edge around the controls.

Answer (score 0):

To change the InsideHeight/InsideWidth you must calculate the actual Height/Width.  To do that, you need to know the width of each userform border and the height of the titlebar.  For example, somewhere in the initialization of the userform do

```
Static FormBorderSize as single, FormTitleSize as single
With Me
  FormBorderSize = (Me.Width-Me.InsideWidth)/2
  FormTitleSize = Me.Height-(Me.InsideHeight+Me.FormBorderSize)
End With
```

With those two values you can compute the overall Height/Width of the userform to get the desired InsideHeight/InsideWidth.

You can declare these two variables as Private or as Public Properties or as shown here as Static.